# AWS Storage gateway : refresh cache Too many requests have been sent to server

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-storage-gateway

I am calling AWS Storage Gateway refreshCache method quite too frequently I guess, (As the message suggests), but I am not sure how long do I need to wait till I hit it again, any help will be appreciated.

```
AWSStorageGateway gatewayClient = AWSStorageGatewayClientBuilder.standard().build();
 RefreshCacheRequest cacheRequest = new RefreshCacheRequest();
 cacheRequest.setFileShareARN(this.fileShareArn);
 gatewayClient.refreshCache(cacheRequest);
```

com.amazonaws.services.storagegateway.model.InvalidGatewayRequestException: Too many requests have been sent to server. (Service: AWSStorageGateway; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidGatewayRequestException; Request ID: f1ffa249-6908-4ae1-9f71-93fe7f26b2af)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1712)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1367)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1113)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can refer to the official document. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/storagegateway/latest/APIReference/API_RefreshCache.html

As it said,

> When this API is called, it only initiates the refresh operation. When the API call completes and returns a success code, it doesn't necessarily mean that the file refresh has completed. You should use the refresh-complete notification to determine that the operation has completed before you check for new files on the gateway file share.

So I guess after you called AWS Storage Gateway refreshCache method, you **must wait until the refresh action completed**. And if you call the method again during this period，some exceptions will be raised.

For the solution, you can refer to [Monitoring Your File Share](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/storagegateway/latest/userguide/monitoring-file-gateway.html#get-notification) to set a notification.

Comment: Thanks , This was helpful. I can proceed from here.